# How to write to media using Python os.write() on Solaris?

Tags: python, unix, operating-system, solaris

I got an error on Python 2.6 for `os.write()` on Solaris v10, failing to open `/proc/partitions`; the path does not exist.
I used this link as reference [proc](http://linux-training.be/storage/ch06.html), understanding that I cannot simply create a file named partitions under `/proc/`.

Is there a workaround to write to media using os.write on Solaris?

Due to operating environment at work, I am constrained to using Solaris currently, but the development originally started on Linux.

Comment: Python2.6 is outdated

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: as I know `/proc` is not real device but virtual device/object created in memory which represents only existing devices/processes/etc. and you can't create new objects. But not all systems may have it - ie. Windows doesn't have it. Solaris may have different method to access partitions on disk.